# Can I reinterpret a memory mapped file of key-value pairs as a map in order to sort them?

Tags: c++, dictionary, mmap, reinterpret-cast

I have a memory mapped file that contains key-value pairs. Both the key and value are uint32_t, and all the keys and values are stored in the file in binary, where a key immediately proceeds the value. The file contains only these pairs, no delimiters.

I want to be able to sort all of these key-value pairs by increasing key.

The following just compiled in my code:

```
struct FileAsMap { map<uint32_t, uint32_t> keyValueMap; };
const FileAsMap* fileAsMap = reinterpret_cast<FileAsMap*>(mmappedData);
```

but I don't really know what to do from here, since by definition the map container keeps a strict weak ordering of the pairs by key. If I just reinterpret the mapped file as a map, how can I get the pairs to order?

Comment: If `map` is `std::map` then unlikely since `std::map` has its own in-memory data structure (e.g. rb-tree). But you could create your own map class which would know what's the structure of the file and interpret it properly.

Comment: Do keys in the file have some order?

Comment: @user3159253 The keys don't necessarily have any order, no.

Comment: No, nothing like this will work. You will have to actually sort the data.

Comment: Then you definitely have to implement the mapping code yourself, because std::map is a tree-based structure with keys having exact appropriate order. Actually, if your data in the file is big enough you'll have to build some ordering on your keys because otherwise table full-scan would be damn slow.

Comment: @user3159253 I maybe misunderstood your question. The keys are unique and integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not an answer but explanations don't fit into comment limitations.

The keys in a map are usually unique (at least in std::map they are). But maps in general differ one from another in method they sort stored keys. For example std::map is based on a balanced binary tree with average complexity of retrieving a given key equal to `O(ln(n))` where `n` is a number of elements in the map. Or e.g. `std::unordered_map` is a hashmap internally with the average access time = O(1). That is it looks for a key in constant time regardless of number of elements inside.

In any case all these data containers demand dedicated internal in-memory structure which practically never looks like a simple stream of key-value pairs. That's why I've told above in the first comment that it's almost impossible to reuse one of standard  maps  as a convenient data accessor for mmap-ed data w/o prior read and unpack the data stream.

But you can create your own map-like class which would iterate over data in mmap-ed area and would check in its `operator[](size_t i)` if a stored key matches the requested one. Iguess that a simplest implementation would take a single screen of code.

But beware: sequental scan is a relatively expensive operation, so if you got *enough* elements in the file, it could become unacceptable slow. In this case you'll need some optimized indexing. For example all keys are read in the beginning of processing and an indexing array is built. But all these questions heavily depend on task details, ao it's better to stop explanations now.

If you have any further questions feel free to ask. Of course a good question assumes that you have already studied the subject and now have encountered a particular problem that you can't solve yoursef

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have already implemented binary search on the mapped file, interpreting the file as an array of 8 byte chunks, and interpreting each 8 byte chunk as an array of two 4 byte chunks (key and value). Could I just implement quick sort or merge sort similarly? Or, would it be possible to perform binary search to find exactly where a new key-value pair would go, then somehow shift the memory down 8 bytes from that point and insert? Or is that a completely dumb idea

Comment: Array is a contiguous block of memory. If you attempt to insert in the middle, then you are not always guaranteed that the current block is extensible. In fact, this could be dangerous. Your best bet is to transfer the array into a vector of key-value pairs and feed it to quick sort/merge sort

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reasons why the answer is no. The two simplest are:

1. Maps are a structure that stores data in a form in which it's already sorted. Your data isn't already sorted, so it's simply not a map.
2. The map class has its own internal data structure that it uses to store maps. Unless your file replicates this internal structure perfectly (which it almost certainly can't since it likely includes pointers into memory) the map class will misunderstand the data in the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
How did u serialize the data to the file?
Assuming that you serialized a struct consisting of maps, you'd de-serialize as below:

FileAsMap* fileAsMap = reinterpret_cast<FileAsMap*>(mmappedData);

Gives access to entire structure (blob).

(*fileAsMap).keyValueMap gives access to map.
```

Comment: No explanation provided, plus you're forgetting so many important caveats it's unreal. And do you even know what `mmappedData` is? And what is `FileAsMap fileAsMap[] = a pointer` supposed to do? It looks like you do not understand C++ arrays.